# Taking the JSON data from Twitter's API and dynamically plotting points on a map using Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, parsing, dictionary

all. 
   I have a gem that is taking the data from Twitter's API and parsing it into JSON. I'm also working with arcgis's mapping system. I'm just trying to figure out if there is a tool, or at least more cohesive method to make the two connect? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe use one of these?
https://github.com/lovehandle/esri-arcgis-geocoder
https://github.com/ajturner/arcgis-ruby

Comment: Thank you! The geocoder one was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this wrapper gem: http://github.com/lovehandle/esri-arcgis-geocoder